# nth-child() selector working only on select few elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="heading-container">
        <p class="stroke">Who we</p>
        <h2 class="section-title extreme-bold">Contact us</h2>
        <p class="stroke"></p>
</div>
```

Now I can select the 1st .stroke using the following selector:

```
.heading-container .stroke:nth-child(1){
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

but the The following does't work for the 2nd stroke class:

```
.heading-container .stroke:nth-child(2){
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

but the following again works:

```
.heading-container .stroke:nth-child(3){
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

Now why does the value 3 work for the 2nd nth-child slection?

For the 2nd nth-child is't the followig suppose to be appropriate:

```
.heading-container .stroke:nth-child(2){
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Try `.stroke:nth-of-type(2){`

Comment: @Tenali i din see that line of code is working?can you please say how that line solved your problem?

Comment: @Leothelion see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kLr59ke6/2/

Comment: @tenali i checked your fiddle and still h2 is not selected but the next one got red background..then?

Comment: @Leothelion , The objective is to select the last .stroke class `.heading-container .stroke:nth-of-type(2){` does the job ,  `.heading-container .stroke:nth-child(2){` deos't .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

nth child, as explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selects based on elements that are the nth child of *their parents*.

so 1 is working, because the first stroke is the first child.
3 works because the second stroke is the third child.
2 won't work, because there are no strokes that are 2nd children, just h2